# get connection with connection_id

Tags: sql-server, connection-pooling, dynamic-management-views

When I execute

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

there will be a resulting column connection_id.

Now, I am searching for the connectionstring which corresponds to this connection_id. Can someone help me, where I can find this information?

Comment: What specific information do you want to get? I don't think there is connectionstring concept in sql server slide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't find connection string info ,like the way it is deployed in web.config..

To identify and isolate connections,you have to use Application name parameter in connection string

> "Data Source =localhost; Initial Catalog=tsql2012;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=testapp";

So whenever application using connection string like above , makes a connection to SQLServer,you can identify it like below..

```
select program_name,client_net_address from sys.sysprocesses sp
join
sys.dm_exec_connections ec
on ec.session_id=sp.spid
 where program_name='testapp'
```